# How to get back the "Insert cell below" button in jupyter NBs in VS Code?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, visual-studio-code

I'm used to having a `+` button below my current working cell when running jupyter notebooks in Visual Studio Code:

[image: screenshot]

It hasn't been updated a while, it's Version 1.51.1 on a Linux machine.

My Windows one has been updated to 1.60.2, and it looks like this now:

[image: screenshot2]

As you can see, the functionality is still there, but now it's hidden in two submenus.
And there's also probably a keyboard shortcut for it, but the `+` was really handy, especially compared to the standard implementation of jupyter notebooks running in the browser.

How can I get the `+` back? I can't seem to find anything in the settings.

[EDIT]
And just when I thought 'Oh well, let's start working anyways, let's see if someone knows an answer...' I accidentally moved my mouse pointer over an hidden button in the bottom middle of the cell and then a button appears!

[image]

And I thought buttons without borders where bad UI, but hidden buttons that only show up if you accidentally stumble upon an arbitrary trigger point, WTF?

I guess it's better than the 3 submenus, but I'd very much would like to have a static, defined and visible button back.